# Using any of the sendEmail functions for the GmailApp class without being blacklisted or having my Gmail account deactivated by Google?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I use any of the sendEmail functions for the GmailApp class ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app ) together with Google Sheets mail merge to send custom emails to the customers of my business without being blacklisted or having my consumer Gmail account deactivated by Google?

Will the customers in some way accept being emailed in this way? If so, how do they do this?

Comment: How do you know you are being blacklisted? What have you tried?

Comment: I sent emails to 50-60 customers late last month and the sending account was deactivated. It might has to do with Google changing their policy last month. It worked fine last year. I wish Google would issue a warning before deactivating the account.

Does anyone else have any experience in sending emails like this or having their account blacklisted or deactivated?

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you have a Spreadsheet where column A contains a number of E-Mail addresses. You can the use the SpreadsheetApp to get all those E-Mail addresses and send a E-Mail to each one.

```
const listOfEmails = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
const subject = "Hi :)"
const body = "Hi, I am sending you this through a script";

listOfEmails.forEach( emailRow => {
   GmailApp.sendEmail( emailRow[0], subject, body )
});
```

There you see how SpreadsheetApp and GmailApp work together. This is the most basic example. There is a whole lot more you can do, for example sending out Drafts from your Gmail, or merging data from Sheets into the E-Mail.

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of script I'm using. How do I prevent having my account blacklisted or deactivated when sending emails using a script like this?

Comment: Don't abuse it. There is quota you have, see reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

To have better delivery you would have to look into DMARC.

Comment: That's exactly what the trouble is. In my opinion, I did not abuse this - never reaching the limit. I only sent out 50-60 emails once a week - one email recipient per email. It seems that DMARC does not apply as I am using a consumer Gmail account for my small business. I am looking for a way to have the recipients approve in Google's systems that they will receive emails from me. If this doesn't exist, it seems that I am driven towards a G Suite subscription.

Comment: Or just look into tools like YAMM https://yet-another-mail-merge.com/ which handle the sending, templating and reporting of the E-Mails you send. There you can see which recipients opened your email.